# Resolving incidents (closing cases) in CRM4 through webservices?

Tags: web-services, dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-4

I'm trying to resolve/close Dynamics CRM4 cases/incidents through webservices.

A single `SetStateIncidentRequest` is not enough and returns a `Server was unable to process request` error message. I think it has something to do with active workflows that trigger on case's attribute changes. I don't know if there's anything else preventing the request to work.

Since it is possible to close those cases through the GUI, I guess there's a "correct" set of steps to follow in order to achieve it through CrmService; unfortunately, I've been googleing it for a while without finding what I want. Could anybody help me, please?

Answer (score 1):

To resolve a case in CRM (in VB.NET), I do the following:

```
Try

Dim activity As New incidentresolution
Dim closeRequest As New CloseIncidentRequest
Dim closeResponse As New CloseIncidentResponse
Dim strErrors As String = String.Empty()

activity.incidentid = New Lookup
activity.incidentid.type = EntityName.incident.ToString
activity.incidentid.Value = //[GUID OF INCIDENT]

activity.ownerid = New Owner
activity.ownerid.type = EntityName.systemuser.ToString
activity.ownerid.Value = //[GUID OF USER PERFORMING ACTION]

activity.statecode = New IncidentResolutionStateInfo
activity.statecode.Value = 1 //Resolved

activity.statuscode = New Status
activity.statuscode.Value = 5 //Problem Solved

closeRequest.IncidentResolution = activity
closeRequest.Status = 5 //Problem Solved

// IF REQUIRED:
activity.timespent = New CrmNumber
activity.timespent.Value = //[INTEGER REPRESENTING No. OF MIN SPENT ON CASE]

closeResponse = objCrm.Execute(closeRequest)

Catch ex As System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapException

    Dim root As XmlElement = ex.Detail
    strErrors = strErrors & vbCrLf & vbCrLf & root.ChildNodes(0).ChildNodes(3).InnerText

    Return False

End Try
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a tip - catch the [SoapException](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.services.protocols.soapexception.aspx) and examine the Detail.OuterXML property and you will get a more detailed error message.  It's possible you're not building your request correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Indeed, I didn't know that there exists a `CloseIncidentRequest` class to use with the `CrmService.Execute()` method. Most probably the `SetStateIncidentRequeset` won't work because it's expected that incident resolutions are created that way. Pity that names for classes and actions aren't used consistently (case/incident, resolution/closing)...